Is it possible to communicate with other third-party COM add ins using the VSTO outlook add-in?
let's suppose I have installed one add-in in my outlook that is COM add-ins in this some API calls processing and also some window dialogue opening I want to develop my own add-in in VSTO technology to record the activity or capture the activity of the user that he is performing in already installed third-party add-in.
For example, he selects anything from the third-party task pane and calls any API or specially records the API call.
Please confirm if using VSTO technology or any other solution is possible.

Possible duplicate of VSTO Addin Bidirectional communication

No, unless that addin was designed to be communicated with (e.g. by exposing the COMAddin.Object property), you cannot do that.
